# The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager in entity framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to delete an object using EntityFramework 5 but i get this error.
*The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager* 
I am using the `Remove()` method as `DeleteObject()` is not present in EF5.
Can anyone help what am I missing?

This does not work for Remove

```
localDb.Customers.Remove(new Customer() { CustomerId = id });
                localDb.SaveChanges();
```

Another thing I tried from msdn to change the state to Deleted. But here it gives an error saying all the fields should be present. Is it necessary to get the complete record then delete?

```
var customer = new Customer(){ CustomerId = id };
                localDb.Customers.Attach(customer);

                localDb.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                localDb.SaveChanges();
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can fetch the row from the database and then delete it, but this causes 2 round trips to the database.

If you want to do it in one hit, your second version with `Attach` will work - as long as the entity is not already loaded into the context.

The error you are getting is caused by EF validation which runs before any database write.

You can turn it off temporarily like this:

```
bool oldValidateOnSaveEnabled = localDb.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled;

try
{
  localDb.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

  var customer = new Customer { CustomerId = id };

  localDb.Customers.Attach(customer);
  localDb.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;
  localDb.SaveChanges();
}
finally
{
  localDb.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = oldValidateOnSaveEnabled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas , just for improving my concept , Why is the validation done on EF side rather than on SQL side? is this the only way for a one hit because this settings seems a lil important to me ... Please correct me if anything is incorrect..

Comment: So far , this is the only answer I believe without causing 2 trips to Db. So marking this as the answer in terms of performance.

Comment: northwind.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
fixed for me , thanks

Comment: u can also do:

localDb.Customers.Attach(customer);
localDb.Customers.Remove(customer;
localDb.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 18):

if you retrieved object from database then it's already attached to the context so you can delete by:

```
db.myTable.Remove(model);
```

**but**
if you just received model from edit or delete view by post or generated it yourself to avoid 2 trips to database then EF doesn't know about it and you get error with above line (..not found in the ObjectStateManager..) so you **set its state to "Deleted" to inform EF** by:

```
//generate it yourself if not posted from edit/delete view
//var model = new Model { Id = 123 };

//set to delete
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Deleted;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you just do this?

```
var customer = localDb.Customers.Single(o => o.CustomerId == id);
localDb.Customers.Remove(customer);
localDb.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yes , but can't we delete an entity with a primary key only? , can we set the primary key or something on those lines?

Comment: What you have in your second example should work actually, have you tried to setting temporary default values for the required fields and deleting? Their values shouldn't matter since you are deleting the object anyway, the primary (entity) key is all that needs to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
public T Delete<T>(T obj) where T : class
        {
            T existing = context.Set<T>().Find(GetKeys(obj, context));

            if (existing != null)
            {
                context.Set<T>().Remove(existing);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return existing;
            }
            return null;
        }

private object[] GetKeys<T>(T entity, DbContext context) where T : class
        {
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            ObjectSet<T> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
            var keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                                        .KeyMembers
                                                        .Select(k => k.Name).ToArray();
            Type type = typeof(T);

            object[] keys = new object[keyNames.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < keyNames.Length; i++)
            {
                keys[i] = type.GetProperty(keyNames[i]).GetValue(entity, null);
            }
            return keys;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but none of the above worked for me since i was deleting registers from more than one class/service at once and each one of them was instantiating it's own database connection context.

What i did to solve it was to send the first created context to the rest of the classes/services that where going to access the database.

For example, my `serviceA` was going to delete some of it's registers and call `serviceB` and `serviceC` to do the same with their registers.

I would then delete my registers on `serviceA` and pass as a parameter the context created on the `serviceA` to `serviceB` and `serviceC`.