# EntityFramework - Cannot Delete Entity using DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I am trying to delete an object from my database using EntityFramework's DbSet. The code is as follows:

```
var dbObject = FindById(id);
_masterDb.DbTable.Remove(dbObject);
_masterDb.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error: "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637965/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the entity is not attached to the same context.

Does this work:

```
var dbObject = FindById(id);
_masterDb.DbTable.Attach(dbObject);
_masterDb.DbTable.Remove(dbObject);
_masterDb.SaveChanges();
```