# The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager when making a crud

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am making a CRUD for admin table from my database and it gives me an error when deleting System.InvalidOperationException: 'The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.'
and the update button does nothing,but if i update that row and than press the delete it does delete it without error

```
  private AdminContext _context;
    private Admin _selectedAdmin;
    public AdminCrudForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _context = new AdminContext();

    }

    private void AdminCrudForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'libraryManagement01DataSet1.Admins' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.adminsTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryManagement01DataSet1.Admins);

    }

    private void DgvAdminCrud_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedAdmin = _context.Admins.Find(DgvAdminCrud.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

        TbAdminID.Text = _selectedAdmin.AdminID.ToString();
        TbAdminFullname.Text = _selectedAdmin.Fullname;
        TbAdminUsername.Text = _selectedAdmin.Username;
        TbAdminPassword.Text = _selectedAdmin.Password;
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            Admin admin = new Admin()
            {
                Fullname = TbAdminFullname.Text,
                Password = TbAdminPassword.Text,
                Username = TbAdminUsername.Text
            };

            _context.Admins.Add(admin);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            this.adminsTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryManagement01DataSet1.Admins);

    }

    private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedAdmin.Fullname = TbAdminFullname.Text;
        _selectedAdmin.Username = TbAdminUsername.Text;
        _selectedAdmin.Password = TbAdminUsername.Text;

        _context.SaveChanges();



        this.adminsTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryManagement01DataSet1.Admins);
    }

    private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Admins.Remove(_selectedAdmin);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        this.adminsTableAdapter.Fill(this.libraryManagement01DataSet1.Admins);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the primary key? Deletes are **very** dangerous operations. The only thing more dangerous is update, as it has less warning signs. So usually you match on the primary key to make *very* certain you get the right thing. Maybe the select does not retreive it, but the update does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager in entity framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637965/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager)